# Real Analysis Upper Bound And Lower Bound

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\sup {A}< \inf(B)$. Show that there exist $ε>0$ and $c \in R$, such that $c+ε$ is a lower bound for $B$ and $c−ε$ is an upper bound for $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is correct.  If you want to be more concrete, you could put 
$$c=\frac{\sup A+\inf B}{2}, \qquad \varepsilon=\frac{\inf B-\sup A}{4}$$
and verify that these values give you the results you want.

Comment: Couldn't $\epsilon$ be $\frac {\inf B- \sup A}2 = c - \sup A = \inf B - c$?  No need for the $4$.

Comment: Definitely.  When I was writing the answer, for some reason I thought we wanted $c-\varepsilon>\sup A$ and $c+\varepsilon<\inf B$, but equality does the job.

Comment: Well, for novice better to err on the side of certainty.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is good (although Aweygan's is better).

It might be worth noting that then we can let $c$ be *any* real number so that $\sup A < c < \inf B$ and let $\epsilon = \min (c - \sup A, \inf B - c)$.  (No need for $c_1$ or $c_2$)

And a suppose if one wanted to be be perverse and choose the $\epsilon$ first rather than the $c$ first, then $\epsilon$ may be *any* real number between $0$ and $\frac {\inf B - \sup A}2$ (exclusively) and therefore $\sup A + \epsilon < \inf B - \epsilon$ and we can allow $c$ to be any real number between $\sup A + \epsilon$ and $\inf B - \epsilon$ (inclusively).